# class Point c++

Tags: c++

Существует ли класс или структура Point (точка) в stl или её аналог?

Comment: @Abyx Смешная шутка. HTTP десятки лет добавить не могут, только-только добрались голые сокеты из буста копипастить, а 2D графику добавят за пару лет без особых обсуждений, ага. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как таковой нет.
Если вам нужна точка на плоскости - вы можете использовать структуру `pair<>`, но она недостаточно удобна (поля - `first` и `second`, а не `x` и `y`).
Можно использовать тот же `array` с фиксированным количеством элементов.

Но проще всего - написать

```
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};
```

и не мучиться :)

Comment: добавлю ещё решение олимпиадников) очень часто удобно хранить в координаты в комплексном типе. X - действительная часть, Y - мнимая. (Иногда -Y) ряд операций достаточно красиво записывается.

Comment: @pavel Ха, а интересное решение...

Answer (score 4):

"Точка" — это понятие, которое **зависит от предметной области**. В математике будет точка координатами double, обычно с двумя или тремя компонентами, но в общем случае число произвольное, причём название компонент может быть разным из-за различных систем координат. В контролах Windows будет точка с двумя координатами int, в каких-то случаях int16_t. В играх наибольшее применение найдут точки с координатами float. В консоли точкой будет пара unsigned int. И это мы ещё не рассматриваем сопутствующие классы, например, вектора и матрицы, и доступные операции между ними.

Как можно видеть, точки могут быть очень разнообразными. В связи с этим вносить в STL класс точки достаточно нецелесообразно: придётся плодить десятки классов с различными типами, именами и количеством компонент, а их применимость будет весьма ограничена из-за отсутствия взаимодействия с классами, которые гармонично сочетаются с классом точки.

Класс точки можно найти в библиотеках, более близких к предметным областям, например, для математических рассчётов, для элементов управления, для движков игр. Используйте их.

Если у вас что-то своё, то не составит труда написать собственный тривиальный класс точки — это две строчки кода.

Comment: Ну, `point<size_t Dimensions, typename Coord_type>` сделать не вопрос, не плодя десятки классов...

Comment: @Harry А поля как назвать? Сколько их сделать? X-Y, X-Y-Z, Left-Top, R-Alpha?

Comment: @Harry Постойте-постойте, `size_t`? Это вы массив предлагаете сделать и обращаться к `X` как `[0]`? Ужас.

Comment: Ну, тогда, как говорится, флаг в руки в написании, скажем, скалярного произведения N-мерных векторов через поля x, y, z, t, u, .... :) В принципе, с именами полей, как мне кажется, тоже можно решить вопрос с использованием вариативных шаблонов. В любом случае я хочу сказать, что концепция точки не входит в STL не потому, что точки могут иметь различные типы полей и их количество. С этим STL отлично справляется...

Comment: @Harry Для n-мерных векторов существуют array и vector. Я не понимаю, чем ваш point будет от них отличаться.

Comment: А я это и написал в своем ответе :) Кстати, `vector` практически 100% не годится - потому что размерность точки по ходу дела меняться не должна...